# GCP: Access to a mysql server from another project with a private IP adress

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-networking

**My problem:**

On google cloud, I have two projects: ProjectA and ProjectB.
In ProjectA I have a mysql server.
In ProjectB I have a virtual machine that needs to connect to the mysql server.
I prefer to use private address (for security, and because mysql filters access from public IPs).

**What I tried:**

I created a network in each project and peered them.
However it doesn't work, I think because by assigning the mysql server to the network, it created a private service connection with an IP range dedicated to services, which isn't peered (it isn't in the exported routes of the peer network).

How to make it work, and what is the good way to do it?

Comment: In Project A, are you using GCP Cloud [SQL](https://cloud.google.com/sql) or are you mounting your SQL server in a Virtual Machine that you manage yourself ?

Comment: @Frank this is in fact a GCP Cloud SQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, there's a GCP VPC Peering [restriction](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/vpc-peering#restrictions) for "transitive peering"

> Only directly peered networks can communicate. Transitive peering is not supported. In other words, if VPC network N1 is peered with N2 and N3, but N2 and N3 are not directly connected, VPC network N2 cannot communicate with VPC network N3 over VPC Network Peering.

When you use a GCP Cloud SQL instance with a private IP, it will automatically create a VPC peering with a different GCP project and yours, this will happen for "Project A" and the moment you peer with "Project B", then you will fall onto this transitive peering limitation.

Here are a couple solutions in order to work around this:

1. Use a [Shared VPC](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/provisioning-shared-vpc#setting_up) in order to have a virtual machine in project b but with a project a network. (limitation, both projects must be on the same organization)
2. Replace the VPC peering between project A and B, with Cloud VPN (I would recommend setting up a Dynamic (BGP) one [HA](https://cloud.google.com/network-connectivity/docs/vpn/how-to/creating-ha-vpn2)/[Classic](https://cloud.google.com/network-connectivity/docs/vpn/how-to/creating-vpn-dynamic-routes)). (limitation, you will be charged with "egress traffic" on each side)
3. Create a virtual machine that can be used as a bridge between them, I tested this before with the following iptables and ip forward enabled:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s <source-ip-range> -o <network-interface> -j MASQUERADE
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i <network-interface> -p tcp --dport <cloud-sql-port> -j DNAT --to <cloud-sql-ip>
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -d <cloud-sql-ip> --dport <cloud-sql-port> -j ACCEPT
```

(limitation, depending on what type of VM you choose, you could be limited in [bandwidth](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/machine-types#n1_machine_types))

Comment: Hi, I also tested with the shared VPC but it doesn't work neither, when I look at the shared IP range it also shares only the sub-network and not the service private IP range

Comment: Shared VPC is for your VM in Project B to be in the same VPC as Project A (and therefore to not use 2 VPC  Network Peerings), you should be able to try this by using nmap, telnet or connecting to your GCP Cloud SQL database internal IP address

If this still doesn't work, use a Shared VPC and place your Project B VM in the same region as your Cloud SQL server

Comment: Thanks you saved my week! I finally made it work using a shared VPC. It took a lot of time to test, because I couldn't ping the database from the VM and thaught it didn't work. However the JDBC driver has access.